# how to pytest an app that can use ipython embed as arg parameter?

Tags: pytest, ipython

I have a python application that has an option "`-y`" to end its procedure in a `ipython` terminal with all objects created ready for an interactive manipulation.

I'm trying to think in how can I design a pytest that could allow me, somehow, to interact with this terminal, to check if objects are there in a python session, exit, and then capture the results for assert (I know how to use `capsys` for example).

During my attempts (all failed so far) I got a suggestion to use `pytest -s` option which, obviously, is not my case.

So I have this example:

*`go_to_python.py`*

```py
import argparse
import random

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
    "-y",
    "--ipython",
    action="store_true",
    dest="ipython",
    help="start iPython interpreter")

args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    randomlist = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        n = random.randint(1, 30)
        randomlist.append(n)

    if args.ipython:
        import IPython

        IPython.embed(colors="neutral")
```

How could I create a test that could `assert` that `randomlist` is inside the `ipython` session?